# Starting shell process under www-data (apache2, php)

Tags: php, linux, shell, apache2

I need to start php process from shell on remove server with some arguments, so i thought that it should be a nice idea to make REST API, that executes some function when user performs GET request.

I wrote a simple bash script for testing and figured out that command-line argument is not being specified, when calling this script from website:

```
shell_exec('/var/www/test.sh 123')
```

Bash script source:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1;
```

When calling this bash script from root (or other existing user) it correctly shows argument it has received. When i call this script from website (that is running under user www-data under apache2), it returns nothing:

Also, if i execute this bash script in my console under www-data user, it also returns nothing:

```
su -c '/var/www/test.sh 123' www-data
```

Also i've tried to start process from different user from php (is supposed that this will not work for security reasons, but just in case):

```
$result = system("su -c '/var/www/test.sh 123' sexyuser", $data);
// var_dump($result): string(0) ""
// var_dump($data): int(1)
```

So, what privileges should i give to www-data user to run process under php?

Comment: what happens if you `echo something $1` in your bash script. you get an output of "something" anywhere?

Comment: It seemed that i had an issue with my daemon i wanted to start, as for bash script.. i can an error in call, i forgot about one quote :((

Comment: So, bash script returns result correctly, i'm idiot :(

Comment: well a typo happens to all of us. No need to bother ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let php run the script and handle the results

check php.net on exec for example http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
//called by example.com/myshell.php?day=today&k=y&whatever=youwant
$arguments = implode(" ", $_GET);
$lastline_of_exec_result = exec ( "/your/command.sh ".$arguments); //sh called with today y youwant
echo $lastline_of_exec;
```

Where $arguments are the stringified list of ALL information your script got from GET arguments

if you want a ore precise in and output, try this:

```
//called by example.com/myshell.php?day=today&k=y&whatever=youwant
$argument = $_GET['whatever'];
$output = array();
$last_line = exec("your/command.sh ".$argument, &$output); //sh called with youwant
foreach($output as $line)
    echo $line."<br/>".PHP_EOL;
```

or of course (with shell_exec)

```
$argument = $_GET['whatever'];
$output = shell_exec("your/command.sh ".$argument);
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

make sure `(shell_)exec` is not listed under `disable_functions` in your php.ini

Comment: How it is possible to grant www-data user rights to execute shell commands? (i suppose problem should be here, i don't remember any special settings in php.ini that disable shell script execution)

Comment: Perhaps problem is not in php, if 'su -c ... www-data' under root gives nothing

Comment: you can disable almost any php function in php.ini incl exec, shell_exec, passthru etc... I suppose the problem you had is that you do not fetch and echo the result of the shell execution.

Comment: you CANNOT su in php... not with lots of effort and special settings first (adding priviliges to www-data to su to name the least) and as far as I remember www-data cannot run shell scripts this way (I cannot recall the source of information, so I'm unsure of that atm)

Comment: perhaps it's easier to use php5-ssh2 package to run shell commands remotely? this way php will login as normal user and execute everything he needs.. i am just afraid of loads (it is possible to have ~50 commands executing same time, so it will be ~50 ssh connections). is it ok?

Comment: in case ssh2 remote authentication (without rest api), there will be no apache, no security issues.

Comment: sorry, never tried that but I'd guess it depends mainly on how much load a single script would induce. I generally like to avoid shell scripts for my projects allthough I do have some here and there, but extended backend privileges for frontend users will never be on my list, I'd rather search for a non-shell workaround ;)

Comment: as for bash script - i had a mistake i my call, i am idiot. as for daemon i wanted to call - there is really strange thing. but i will talk about it with daemon's developers to figure that out, perhaps daemon needs more rights to be started then bash.sh script